# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Could not allocate JNI Env always android java

Tags: java, android

i am running AsyncTask

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Could not allocate JNI Env
                                                                         at java.lang.Thread.nativeCreate(Native Method)
                                                                         at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:1063)
                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:921)
                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.processWorkerExit(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:989)
                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1131)
                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                                         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

i get this error the next time i run the app and do the same task,first time task is completed without any porblem and no crashes and when i back press and exit the app and come back and do the same task it shows this error

```
[ 11-06 22:20:02.741  1174: 1219 D/         ]
                                                                 NULL == 

surf->write_back_color_buffer
11-06 22:20:02.741 1174-1219/com.package A/OpenGLRenderer: Encountered EGL error 12291 EGL_BAD_ALLOC during rendering
11-06 22:20:02.741 1174-1219/com.package A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 1219 (RenderThread)
```

never had this problem before

Answer (score 3, accepted):

okay that error was due to inputstream i forgot to close in one module,so if you guys use any stream,double check it and make sure you close all stream  you open :)